# Is there a UPS with open source power maganement software?

Tags: power-supply, power-control, ups

I wonder if there is a UPS power supply with an open source power monitoring application? To be more clear, I need to automatically store data such as remaining battery or power consumption and write a program that automatically processes this data on a Linux OS.

Current UPS devices have power management software (such as amazon basic), but they do not provide the user with the ability of live communication with the UPS.

Comment: You may try **UPS Communicator**. I'm just not sure if it works only with Legrand hardware only or not. So, you may test it. https://ups.legrand.com/en/software/software-download

Comment: @Kirby Thank you. I was looking for something like this. But apparently, the voltage standard of Legrand products are not for Canada (ranging from 180-240). I wonder if there is another option or solution? Thanks

Comment: I believe APC makes UPS models that have this [kind of functionality](https://www.apc.com/ca/en/support/product-support/ups-management-software-guide.jsp) but you should explain what you actually need "live" data for, it looks like most of these UPS systems would make your homemade program redundant because they monitor battery level to manage services and energy consumption.

Comment: @Romen Thank you for your suggestion. Basically, I need the send commands to the UPS through command line or, for example, python code and get the data from the UPS. Not with a host app that installs on the computer and gives you all the functionality.

Comment: What if the host app does have an API though? (So you talk to the app instead of the hardware directly). If you want to "talk" to a UPS directly you're going to need something like a server UPS that has a network management port.

Answer (score 2):

There is the fairly well-known free and opensource UPS monitoring tool [NUT](https://networkupstools.org/). It's available from the software repositories of major GNU/Linux and BSD distribution, including the OpenWRT distribution for routers.

I've used it in the past to log UPS data using simple shell scripts. The only requirement for using NUT is a communication port on the UPS, which could be a USB or an old-fashioned RS-232 cable. Most UPS systems with a communication port should work in dumb mode that would allow you to receive data from the UPS, if not send commands to it.

NUT is designed on a client/server model, where the interface is separate from the back-end.